# Verifying clients when using interprocess communication

Tags: windows, linux, macos, security, ipc

I'm building an application that will provide a service to other applications (let's pretend like it solves differential equations). So my DifEq service will be running all the time and a client application can send it requests to solve DifEqs at any point.

This would be trivial using sockets or pipes.

The problem is some applications nefariously want to send linear equations instead of differential equations, so I want to register applications that I know are sending proper DifEqs to my application.

Traditional sockets break down here, as far as I know.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to look at some information about the application that is making a request of me and (either through some meta-data on that application, through communication with my web site, or through some other, unkown method) determine it is an acceptable DifEq app. Furthermore, this ideal method would not be spoofable without a root/admin-level compromise of the underlying OS. If the linear equation app is also a root kit, I'll concede to being broken. :)

I need to be able to do this on Windows, OS X, and Linux (and maybe Android); but I recognize that it may not be the same solution on all platforms. So, how would you accomplish this (specify the platform you are focusing on, if appropriate)? I've done a lot of server-side development, but it's been *way too many* years since I've done any client-side development outside the browser and the world is very different today than it was then.

Comment: I don't think I get it.  Sounds like to me:  

1.  Accept any connection
2.  Process Requests
3.  If someone gives you a bad request, disconnect them.
4.  Consider a blacklist, and stop accepting connections from them for a timeout?

Comment: In the real application, I have no way of knowing whether a request is "good" or "bad". I'm hoping to be able to tag data such that I know it came from "Client A" versus "Client B", but it does me no good to do so if it is trivially easy for Client B to imitate Client A.  Even assuming I could differentiate requests, how would I know which clients were making bad requests (assuming connections aren't persistant)?  Remember, this is all on the same machine, so (if this is possible, which is a stretch, I realize) it would have to be an OS-level operation to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a little confusing when it comes to talking about DifEQ vs LinearEQ.

It sounds to me like you are just looking for a routine way to verify that clients are authorized to connect.  There is a lot to read up on this subject.  Common methods would be to use SSL certificates to verify the identity of clients.  You can also tunnel over SSH, or use OAUTH, etc, etc.

You'll have to do some more digging around the web to see what kind of authentication fits your scenario.  You mention 'not spoofable'.  I think that people generally end up compiling-in a certificate of private key into their application.  This will stop all but the very dedicated and experienced hackers.